# Strange Issue with Video File Upload in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I am building a video site on CodeIgniter (v 2.1.0). The admins can upload videos via admin panel. It works perfectly on my local server. But on remote test server, it's not working. I have set the mimes.php to recognize the file-type correctly. The allowed file-types are okay. But the error message says the file-type isn't permitted.
Here's my mimes.php:

```
...
'mp4'  => 'video/mp4',
'flv'  => 'video/x-flv',
'avi' => 'video/x-msvideo',
'mpeg' => 'video/mpeg',
...
```

Alowed file-types:

```
$upload_config['allowed_types'] = 'flv|mp4|avi|mpeg'
```

Upload library is initialised with `$this->upload->initialize($upload_config);` If I do a var_dump for $_FILES it gives me:

```
array(1) { ["video_file"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(48) "test_video_file.mp4" ["type"]=> string(9) "video/mp4" ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpwkOICI" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(5668643) } }
```

What is wrong with it? What drives me nuts is that the same script works fine on my local machine but doesn't work on remote test sub-domain. And every debug message looks legit to me. Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks and regards

Comment: try `$this->upload->display_errors()` and see what error throws

Comment: if your remote is an Apache server, what does your .htaccess file look like?

Comment: @safarov the error is "The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed."

Comment: @timpeterson .htaccess is same as in local server: http://pastebin.com/EqAAnB52 Don't know if it's important, but the remote server is under VPS hosting. And honestly, I never managed VPS myself, so I don't know if I need to change anything there.

Comment: hmm, its not about the hosting per se but the actual server configuration. The PHP is correct if it works on your local machine.

Comment: Is the `Avi` mime-type you mentioned the most commonly used one?  Perhaps your remote server prefers `video/avi` whereas your local machine is ok with the `video/x-msvideo`?http://filext.com/file-extension/AVI

Comment: @timpeterson well, I don't think avi mime-type is an issue. None of the files I uploaded was an avi file but still CI is throwing the error.

Comment: i'm out of suggestions, did you try what Safarov said about uploading a jpg,png on your remote server?

Comment: @timpeterson yes, I tried _all_ the fixes in the thread. No luck. :-(

Comment: seems like might be good to inquire to VPS or admins you mention on mime-type settings and whether you can change them, this mime-type stuff seems like it'd be routine for people with decent experience with servers, i'm not very experienced as you can probably tell

Comment: @timpeterson Here are the mime-types settings for the host: http://pastebin.com/AsuZKBZV Looks like the mimetypes here match with my mimes.php

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9650/discussion-between-abhisek-and-tim-peterson)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its a bug on v 2.1.0. Try these instructions to fix the issue http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/204725/

Comment: No dice. Just tried the fix. Still the error. I have feeling it has something to do with the server settings. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  After looking in the Apache logs, it turned out to be a PHP setting... the uploaded file size was too big. So to avoid having to remember to change the PHP settings on every server I might be running the site on, I modified the .htaccess file by adding these two lines:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M

php_value post_max_size 10M
```

Found the answer here: [https://www.dokuwiki.org/faq:uploadsize](https://www.dokuwiki.org/faq%3auploadsize)